# Allowing SizeToContent to enlarge the size but not reduce it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a window with a tabbed control inside, which contains controls of different sizes in each tab. I'm using SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" in my Window, but I would like to allow it to only enlarge the window size.

For example, if I move to a 'bigger' tab, I want my control to adapt its size automatically, but if I then go back to the 'smaller' tab, I don't want my control to reduce its size again. I would prefer to not use MinWidth and MinHeight as I would like that my users are able to manually reduce the window size.

Thank you

Comment: This can give you an idea:You should handle Width and Height Properties changed events. If they are going to be bigger, set `SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight"`, if not, you should try to stop this from happening.

Comment: @Ramin Thanks for the advice. I would think SizeToContent should be WidthAndHeight already, shouldn't it? Anyway, intercepting the change could work, but then I think I would have to set the width and/or height to the old value, and, AFAIK, SizeToContent doesn't work with fixed height/width

Comment: I meant, if size is going to be smaller, you should set SizeToContent to be Manual and then preserve the previous size. If the size is going to be bigger, set SizeToContent to be WidthAndHeight. If there where a PropertyChanging event, I think it was straight (set SizeToContent=Manual and Cancel Width and Height changes, when it is getting smaller), But I think there is no suxh an event. So, you can handle Width and Height Changed events. If they got bigger, just set the SizeToContent=WidthAndHeight. If they got smaller, set SizeToContent=Manual and set Height and Width to the bigger ones.

Comment: @Ramin The problem is that then it wouldn't increase its size if I go to an even bigger tab. Suppose I do this: Main tab -> Bigger tab -> Smaller tab (until here it is correct because it doesn't reduce its size) -> Even bigger tab (wrong, it doesn't adapt its size anymore)

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example;

The Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationUpper.Window3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window3" Height="300" Width="300" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Grid>
    <TabControl Name="MainTabControl" 
                SelectionChanged="MainTabControl_SelectionChanged" 
                PreviewMouseDown="MainTabControl_PreviewMouseDown">
        <TabItem Header="Small Tab" >
            <Border Background="AliceBlue" Width="200" Height="200" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Medium Tab">
            <Border Background="Blue" Width="400" Height="400" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Large Tab">
            <Border Background="Navy" Width="600" Height="600" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind:

```
  public partial class Window3 : Window
  {
    public Window3() {InitializeComponent();}
    double _currentWidth;
    double _currentHeight;
    private void MainTabControl_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItem currentItem = MainTabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem;
        FrameworkElement content = currentItem.Content as FrameworkElement;
        _currentWidth = content.ActualWidth;
        _currentHeight = content.ActualHeight;
    }
    private void MainTabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItem itemAdded = null;
        TabItem itemRemoved = null;
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
            itemAdded = e.AddedItems[0] as TabItem;
        if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
            itemRemoved = e.RemovedItems[0] as TabItem;

        if (itemAdded != null && itemRemoved != null)
        {
            FrameworkElement content = itemAdded.Content as FrameworkElement;
            double newWidth = content.Width;
            double newHeight = content.Height;
            if (newWidth < _currentWidth)
                content.Width = _currentWidth;
            if (newHeight < _currentHeight)
                content.Height = _currentHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is a little ugly, but it is better that nothing :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution is not that bad, but I'd like to wait to see if there is a 'cleaner' approach. I don't like, specifically, have to check when the current tab changes, as there could be other situations when the size should change (like when the contents of the current tab increase its size). Also, all my controls have Height and Width set to Auto, so I don't think that using its Width and Height properties work. I would think I have to use ActualWidth and ActualHeight